# how to Highlight bookmark text using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am new to google app script. I am looking for highlight bookmark text. Like I have a bookmark and on click event I want to highlight the Bookmark text. Eg. Bookmark is B_123 and text of that bookmark is "Hi, I am the bookmark text value". On button click event I want to jump at the bookmark page location and highlight it by bold it or by applying some CSS. How can I active it?

I have tried below thing:

DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBookmark("abc").getPosition()

But after position object there is not any standard function for jump to bookmark location or apply some CSS to the bookmark text

Comment: There is no button in Google Docs like there is in Spreadsheet.  You can make a sidebar menu using HTML Service.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not actually. I have a bookmark and placed some text on the bookmark. Now I am looking app script which can highlight the bookmark text

Comment: What "On button click event" are you refering to?

Comment: Highlight the bookmark text.